# Spring Data JPA: How to get parent entity with childentity Ids only instead of whole child entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring Data JPA setup with entities Player and Rating. In my use case, I want to retrieve all ratings for a specific user by their ID. However, I don't want to fetch the complete User entity for each rating; instead, I only need the user ID for example or nothing, similar to how it's stored in the database.

Is there a way to achieve this in Spring Data JPA, perhaps through a custom query or projection, to optimize the performance by avoiding the unnecessary loading of the complete User entity for each rating?

Is there an optimized way? At the moment it just maps to DTOs after the call, i think it's not well optimize.

**Entities**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Rating {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RatingId ratingId;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("playerId")
    @NotNull
    private Player player;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("gameId")
    @NotNull
    private Game game;

    private float points;

    @ManyToOne
    private Platform platform;

    private Long startDate;

    private Long endDate;

    private Status status;

    public Rating(Player player, Game game) {
        this.ratingId = new RatingId(player.getId(), game.getId());
        this.player = player;
        this.game = game;
    }
}

@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public Player(String username, String email, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

}

@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RatingId implements Serializable {

    private Long playerId;
    private Long gameId;
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface RatingRepository extends JpaRepository<Rating, RatingId> {
    List<Rating> findAllByPlayerId(Long playerId);
}
```

When i do it directly in the database:

```
database=# select * from rating where rating.player_id = 1;

 end_date | points | start_date | status | player_id | game_id | platform_id
----------+--------+------------+--------+-----------+---------+-------------
          |    1.5 |            |      0 |         1 |    9174 |           6
```

Comment: Could you also share your DTO where you map the result of the query ?

Comment: in the DTO i just remove the player entity.

Comment: you have got an answer to your question that I also meant to give you

Comment: Yeah i saw it. Does it help with performance. The whole point, why i want to do it like this. Is, when i call 1000 ratings from an player_id. I dont to call 1000times the same player object.

Comment: Why do you use **MapsId** in Rating class? It is used for **one-to-one** mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom query or projection in Spring Data JPA. One way to achieve this is by using a DTO (Data Transfer Object) projection to retrieve only the necessary information.

```
public class RatingDTO {
    private Long playerId;
    private float points;
    private Long startDate;
    private Long endDate;
    private Status status;

    // Constructor, getters, and setters
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface RatingRepository extends JpaRepository<Rating, RatingId> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.example.dto.RatingDTO(r.player.id, r.points, r.startDate, r.endDate, r.status) FROM Rating r WHERE r.player.id = :playerId")
    List<RatingDTO> findAllByPlayerId(Long playerId);
}
```

Now, when you call `findAllByPlayerId` method, it will return a list of `RatingDTO` objects containing only the necessary information without fetching the complete `Player` entity.

Remember to adjust the package name `(com.example.dto)` according to your project structure. Additionally, you may need to handle null values for optional associations, such as platform in the Rating entity, if they are nullable in the database.

Comment: Does it help with performance. The whole point, why i want to do it like this. Is, when i call 1000 ratings from an player_id. I dont to call 1000times the same player object.

Comment: I dont get your point. Here playerID is foreign key in Rating table. So this query will only run on rating table, not player table.